# importing font-awesome causing x-axis overflow on Chrome Mobile

Tags: html, css, font-awesome, bulma

I have a pretty weird situation here. 
I have this HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Notes</title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.2/css/bulma.min.css">
      <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/js/all.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="columns is-multiline">
         <div class="column is-one-third">
            <div class="card">
               <header class="card-header">
                  <p class="card-header-title">
                     test1
                  </p>
                  <a href="/notes/pin/1" class="card-header-icon" aria-label="more options">
                  <span class="icon">
                  <i class="fas fa-thumbtack" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  </span>
                  </a>
               </header>
               <div class="card-content">
                  <div class="content">
                     <p>testtt</p>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <footer class="card-footer">
                  <a href="/notes/edit/1/" class="card-footer-item">Edit/View</a>
                  <a href="/notes/delete/1/" class="card-footer-item">Delete</a>
               </footer>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="column is-one-third">
            <div class="card">
               <header class="card-header">
                  <p class="card-header-title">
                     Note test
                  </p>
                  <a href="/notes/pin/4" class="card-header-icon" aria-label="more options">
                  <span class="icon">
                  <i class="fas fa-thumbtack" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  </span>
                  </a>
               </header>
               <div class="card-content">
                  <div class="content">
                     <p>- test</p>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <footer class="card-footer">
                  <a href="/notes/edit/4/" class="card-footer-item">Edit/View</a>
                  <a href="/notes/delete/4/" class="card-footer-item">Delete</a>
               </footer>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div style="padding-top:50px;"></div>
      <!--- NON-PINNED -->
      <div class="columns is-multiline">
         <div class="column is-one-third">
            <div class="card">
               <header class="card-header">
                  <p class="card-header-title">
                     Note test
                  </p>
                  <a href="/notes/pin/2" class="card-header-icon" aria-label="more options">
                  <span class="icon">
                  <i class="fas fa-thumbtack" style="color:lightgrey;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  </span>
                  </a>
               </header>
               <div class="card-content">
                  <div class="content">
                     <p>Testi</p>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <footer class="card-footer">
                  <a href="/notes/edit/2/" class="card-footer-item">Edit/View</a>
                  <a href="/notes/delete/2/" class="card-footer-item">Delete</a>
               </footer>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="column is-one-third">
            <div class="card">
               <header class="card-header">
                  <p class="card-header-title">
                     Dhchjc
                  </p>
                  <a href="/notes/pin/3" class="card-header-icon" aria-label="more options">
                  <span class="icon">
                  <i class="fas fa-thumbtack" style="color:lightgrey;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  </span>
                  </a>
               </header>
               <div class="card-content">
                  <div class="content">
                     <p>Djfjgn<br>- eat </p>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <footer class="card-footer">
                  <a href="/notes/edit/3/" class="card-footer-item">Edit/View</a>
                  <a href="/notes/delete/3/" class="card-footer-item">Delete</a>
               </footer>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="column is-one-third">
            <div class="card">
               <header class="card-header">
                  <p class="card-header-title">
                     Fhfj
                  </p>
                  <a href="/notes/pin/5" class="card-header-icon" aria-label="more options">
                  <span class="icon">
                  <i class="fas fa-thumbtack" style="color:lightgrey;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  </span>
                  </a>
               </header>
               <div class="card-content">
                  <div class="content">
                     <p>Brjdjc</p>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <footer class="card-footer">
                  <a href="/notes/edit/5/" class="card-footer-item">Edit/View</a>
                  <a href="/notes/delete/5/" class="card-footer-item">Delete</a>
               </footer>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <a href="/notes/new/">
         <div id="floating-button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" data-original-title="Create">
            <p class="plus">+</p>
         </div>
      </a>
   </body>
</html>
```

And my CSS:

```
#floating-button {
    width: 55px;
    height: 55px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #db4437;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 30px;
    right: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px #666;
}

.plus {
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    display: block;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 55px;
    font-size: 38px;
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    font-weight: 300;
}

.column {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.card {
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    max-height: 500px;
}
```

- When viewing on regular desktop mode, everything is fine.
- When on Chrome + mobile viewport, there is a slight overflow on the x axis.
- When viewing on Firefox + mobile viewport, it is fine.
- **When removing the `script` tag importing Font-Awesome, there are no longer any problems on Chrome. The font-awesome CSS CDN also causes this.**

There are two `columns` because one is for pinned notes (displayed first) and the other for regular ones.

## The problem

When on Chrome with mobile viewport, the page width is larger than the viewport, but not with Firefox. I fixed it by remove the `script` tag importing Font-Awesome, but I would need font awesome and it's icons.

Comment: Please, what is the problem?. Be specific.

Comment: @Yoarthur Edited

Comment: In the first `.columns multiline` you define just two `.is-one-third`. Should you define three so bulma can know the width of the columns he'll span?.

Comment: I want to have 3 cards per row. I added multiline so that it spans multiple lines. Also these cards are dynamically generated - so there coulde 3 or 20 cards in the first `columns`. I'm an HTML newbie so I hope I'm doing this right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed this by adding `.columns { margin-right:0px;margin-left:0px;}` to the CSS. See [this](https://github.com/jgthms/bulma/issues/766) bulma issue.